# MongoDB Node Driver with Binary Data Field

Tags: mongodb, node.js

I have a series of records in MongoDB with a smallish binary field.  When I query it with mongodb-node and do `console.log(my_record);` then I see the record just fine in apparent binary form.  I want to get the data and convert it to base 64 before sending back to client.  I've tried `new Buffer(my_record.binary,'base64')` but it complains of bad argument.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You have to read the data in binary, and output it in base64. I guess, you have to do something of this sort:

```
buffer = new Buffer(my_record.binary,'binary')
hex = buffer.toString('base64')
```

Comment: That seems to work, but the resulting base64 isn't correct (at least the image isn't displaying properly.

Comment: Not sure what to say, you can always look into mongodb-native source code to see what is happening. https://github.com/christkv/node-mongodb-native/blob/master/lib/mongodb/bson/binary.js , My other suggestion would be my_record.binary.buffer.toString('base64')